# Enable and disable different component on a Gameobject

Tags: unity, c#

So far I am not clear how do you actually access the various components on a game object, to enable and disable them.

I have a component that has various scripts and elements, like a camera, transform, audio listener and few other custom scripts.

It is in the scene, so I try to access to it via script:

```
private GameObject _player;

_player = GameObject.Find("the_player")
```

So far so good; if I want to access for example to the camera, and enable or disable it, I can do it

```
    _player.GetComponent<Camera>().enabled = true;
```

This disable correctly the camera, or eanble it, depending from the paramenter that I pass.

Now, if I want to access my script, called "playerscript"; I can't do the same thing, since I get an error:

```
    _player.GetComponent<playerscript>().enabled = true;
```

Not sure why I get an error; I have a class that is called "playerscript", that is attached to that _player object, but instead, VS complain.

This is the error message:

```
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'playerscript' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I did try to use also GetComponentInChildren, but the result is the same.

If I have the object _player, which hold a reference to the original game object instantiated in the scene, why I can't simply access all the elements attached to it, via GetComponent and dot notation? I believe this used to work time ago, but in Unity5 I can't get this to work.

EDIT: This is the content of the playerscript class:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class playerscript : MonoBehaviour
{    
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        // get the instance of the button from UI manager
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider world_item)
    {
        //enable item animation
    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider world_item)
    {
        //disable item animation
    }
}
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: For safe side did you try to first turn on your script and get it?

Comment: Are you sure they're in the same namespace or that you've imported the namespace `playerscript` is in?

Comment: What's the error message? playerscript needs to extend MonoBehaviour!

Comment: The error is CS0246 "the type or namespace could not be found. I did check the namespace and I use none. They are plain scripts used as controllers, that interact with my model classes.

Comment: That's the compiler telling you it doesn't know what "playerscript" is supposed to refer to. If you've already eliminated namespaces or other uses that would require qualifying the name, then it could be that you've spelled "playerscript" differently in the class definition (case matters). Can we see an excerpt of the playerscript class?

Comment: I didn't mispell it, that was my first thought and I did copy and paste it, to be safe. Adding the file content in the question

Comment: I should point out that this happen for any script that I add, or for assets that I purchase on the asset store, which use custom scripts. I can retrieve the components that are native in Unity, like Camera or Audio Listener.

Comment: The error has nothing to do with getting a component, that's a red herring. Are you getting any other compile errors that could be preventing the compiler from adding these scripts to its collection of known names?

Comment: No, everything works fine; the error is raised only when I use one of my scripts,called via GetComponent. Tried with angle bracket and round bracket and with quotes; nothing works. If I enable or disable the script from the Editor, while the game is running, it works just fine. I suspect that something is wrong with VS at this point, because it make no sense....all the posts that I have foumd, use the same syntax; and I get the error on any script, even if I create an empty one from Unity Editor.

Comment: Did you try to close solution in VS and reopen it manually?

Comment: Right you are, Hamza....I did close VS, close Unity; open Unity again and double click on the script in Unity, which opened VS again. Now VS is able to see the scripts correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The solution came from Hamza's suggestion: close VS and start it again.

Once I did restart VS, now it is able to recognize correctly the scripts without problem.

I guess the issue is that VS get stuck sometimes, and does not see scripts created by the user, until you restart it. I will file a bug report to Microsoft to point out the issue.

If it ever happen to you; restart Unity and then launch VS double clicking on a script in Unity; which will restart VS.